# TYPO3 news is overwriting flexform action with get param

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, tx-news

I have multiple news plugins (tx_news) on my TYPO3 website [www.meinetolleseite42.de](http://www.meinetolleseite42.de). These plugins display a list view of articles - this works as intended. but if I now call up such a url (as sometimes happens through crawling) [www.meinetolleseite42.de?tx_news_pi1[action]=detail&tx_news_pi1[controller]=News&tx_news_pi1[news]=265003](http://www.meinetolleseite42.de?tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=detail&tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=265003) then the detail template is suddenly rendered in the list plugins. how can I prevent the get parameter from overwriting the flexform? disableOverwrite is active in the plugin.

using TYPO3 10.4 and tx_news 8.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 different list modes are available.

- List item
- List view (without overloading detail view)

Just select the second one.

https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/11.3/en-us/UsersManual/Plugins/Index.html#list

Comment: that was too easy. thanks